# Twig, get source

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How I can get template with `extend`:

```
//first.html.twig
<div>
{% block test %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

And `second.html.twig`:

```
{% extend "first.html.twig" %}
{% block test %}
    {% if test = 'foo' %}
        {{ test }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

In php file:

```
<?php
    $load = ???('second.html.twig');
    $source = $load->getSource();
    //$source:
    //<div>
    //    {% if test = 'foo' %}
    //        {{ test }}
    //    {% endif %}
    //</div>
```

Comment: I think you should explain the context, develop your question. What are you really  looking for ?

Comment: @AnthonyB I want send twig for parsing in other server, and want send some source with json, and get response with render html.

Comment: I understand now, thanks. Is the path correct ? In Twig engine it's possible to set a template directory, is first.html.twig in this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#dynamic-inheritance) you can set a layout to a template. Example:

From documentation

```
// {% extends layout %}

// deprecated as of Twig 1.28
$layout = $twig->loadTemplate('some_layout_template.twig');

// as of Twig 1.28
$layout = $twig->load('some_layout_template.twig');

$twig->display('template.twig', array('layout' => $layout));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you want to place the data from twig file #1 into #2 and then display #2 with its own content as well as that of #1.

I don't know if you are getting any errors. but the best way to do this is use the `{% include %}` option info on this can be found here [include](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#including-templates)

Comment: I want in php get solid template with out `extend` or `includ`

Comment: @Iwan Twig is compiled into `PHP`, you can't get the source you are after afaik, only the compiled `PHP` source